# How to render deck.gl Arcs go over Pacific Ocean

Tags: mapbox, deck.gl, react-map-gl

I am trying to draw arcs from China to US, but the arcs don't cross over the Pacific Ocean. They go over the Atlantic Ocean and over Europe instead.

Is there a way for arcs to draw over the Pacific Ocean?

[image: Deck.gl arc layer not going over Pacific Ocean]

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but to help new people out. You can use some of the more modern features in deck.gl.

You should consider using the [greatCircle](https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/layers/arc-layer#greatcircle) (for arc layers only) option or [wrapLongitude](https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/core/layer#wraplongitude) (more generic for all layers).

To get the longitudinally wrapped layers to work across the antimeridian (eg when the map is centered on the pacific ocean) you could also consider using the `repeat` function available under `MapView` [docs here](https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/core/map-view).